# Merge two XML streams using XSLT matching on key values

Tags: xslt

I would like to know how to merge 2 XML streams before finally transforming it again.

The two streams are

**Input 1**

```
<Response>
    <Instrument>
        <Date value="2010-09-02">
            <Quantity>10</Quantity>
        </Date>
        <DXLID>1</DXLID>
    </Instrument>
    <Instrument TICKER="APPL" />
    <SF></SF>
    <Instrument>
        <Date value="2010-09-02">
            <Quantity>20</Quantity>
        </Date>
        <DXLID>2</DXLID>
    </Instrument>
    <Instrument TICKER="APPL" />
    <SF></SF>
</Response>
```

**Input 2**

```
<Response>
    <IM>
        <Instrument>
            <Date value="2010-09-02">
                <SAF>1</SAF>
                <SAR>2</SAR>
            </Date>
            <DXLID>1</DXLID>
        </Instrument>
        <Instrument>
            <Date value="2010-09-02">
                <SAF>1</SAF>
                <SAR>2</SAR>
            </Date>
            <DXLID>3</DXLID>
        </Instrument>
    </IM>
</Response>
```

**Desired Output**

```
<Response>
    <All>
        <Instrument>
            <Date value="2010-09-02">
                <SAF>1</SAF>
                <SAR>2</SAR>
                <Quantity>10</Quantity>
            </Date>
            <DXLID>1</DXLID>
        </Instrument>
        <Instrument>
            <Date value="2010-09-02">
                <Quantity>20</Quantity>
            </Date>
            <DXLID>2</DXLID>
        </Instrument>
        <Instrument>
            <Date value="2010-09-02">
                <SAF>1</SAF>
                <SAR>2</SAR>
            </Date>
            <DXLID>3</DXLID>
        </Instrument>
    </All>
</Response>
```

The merge needs to be based on a match between the `DXLID` node value and the `value` attribute of the `Date` node.

Note also that the merge needs to be a merge both ways.

Comment: I've edited your input samples to be wellformed. Rollback if there is differences. Also, you don't need to merge this before transformation: `fn:document` allows multiple input source. If you add your second step transformation someone could provide an example.

Comment: @Neil-Gallagher: You need to specify in your question how should identically named and positioned elements be processed. For example, if there is `/*/*/Instrument/Date/Saf` in both documents, but the values of the two elements are different, then which of these two values should be chosen?

Comment: @Neil-Gallagher: See my answer for a solution that doesn't perform set membership operations with the `count()` function.

Answer (score 2):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="kInstrumentByDateAndDXLID" match="Instrument"
             use="concat(Date/@value,'++',DXLID)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vSource1"
               select="document('Doc1.xml')/Response/Instrument[Date][DXLID]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vSource2"
               select="document('Doc2.xml')/Response/IM/Instrument"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Response>
            <All>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$vSource1|$vSource2">
                    <xsl:sort select="DXLID"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </All>
        </Response>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Date/*[last()]">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <xsl:if test="count(../..|$vSource1)=count($vSource1)">
            <xsl:variable name="vKey"
                          select="concat(../@value,'++',../../DXLID)"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$vSource2[last()]">
                <xsl:apply-templates
                 select="key('kInstrumentByDateAndDXLID',$vKey)/Date/*"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Instrument">
        <xsl:if test="count(.|$vSource1)=count($vSource1) or
                      not($vSource1[key('kInstrumentByDateAndDXLID',
                                        concat(current()/Date/@value,'++',
                                               current()/DXLID))])">
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<Response>
    <All>
        <Instrument>
            <Date value="2010-09-02">
                <Quantity>10</Quantity>
                <SAF>1</SAF>
                <SAR>2</SAR>
            </Date>
            <DXLID>1</DXLID>
        </Instrument>
        <Instrument>
            <Date value="2010-09-02">
                <Quantity>20</Quantity>
            </Date>
            <DXLID>2</DXLID>
        </Instrument>
        <Instrument>
            <Date value="2010-09-02">
                <SAF>1</SAF>
                <SAR>2</SAR>
            </Date>
            <DXLID>3</DXLID>
        </Instrument>
    </All>
</Response>
```

**Note**: The use of apply-templates allows to run the merge and second step transformation at once. Also, the use of `fn:document` for multiple input source, and XPath test for inclusion: `count($node|$node-set)=count($node-set)`

**Edit**: the same with keys. It looks like MSXSL4 has a bug, that's why I'm ussing `$vSource2[last()]` instead of `$vSource2[1]`

Answer (score 0):

**This transformation** (includes the entire second document -- just for convenience):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kDateByValAndId" match="Date"
  use="concat(@value, '+', ../DXLID)"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc1" select="/"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vrtfDoc2">
    <Response>
        <IM>
            <Instrument>
                <Date value="2010-09-02">
                    <SAF>1</SAF>
                    <SAR>2</SAR>
                </Date>
                <DXLID>1</DXLID>
            </Instrument>
            <Instrument>
                <Date value="2010-09-02">
                    <SAF>1</SAF>
                    <SAR>2</SAR>
                </Date>
                <DXLID>3</DXLID>
            </Instrument>
        </IM>
    </Response>
 </xsl:variable>

 <xsl:variable name="vDoc2" select=
  "document('')/*/xsl:variable[@name='vrtfDoc2']"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <Response>
   <All>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/*/node()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="doc2" select=
     "$vDoc2/*/*/Instrument[Date and DXLID]" />
   </All>
  </Response>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Date">
  <xsl:variable name="vkeyVal" select=
  "concat(@value, '+', ../DXLID)"/>

  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
   <xsl:for-each select="$vDoc2">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kDateByValAndId', $vkeyVal)/node()"/>
   </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="SF|Instrument[@TICKER='APPL']"/>

 <xsl:template match="Instrument" mode="doc2">
  <xsl:variable name="vkeyVal" select=
  "concat(Date/@value, '+', DXLID)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vcur" select="."/>

  <xsl:for-each select="$vDoc1">
   <xsl:if test="not(key('kDateByValAndId', $vkeyVal))">
    <xsl:copy-of select="$vcur"/>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the original 1st document**:

```
<Response>
    <Instrument>
        <Date value="2010-09-02">
            <Quantity>10</Quantity>
        </Date>
        <DXLID>1</DXLID>
    </Instrument>
    <Instrument TICKER="APPL" />
    <SF></SF>
    <Instrument>
        <Date value="2010-09-02">
            <Quantity>20</Quantity>
        </Date>
        <DXLID>2</DXLID>
    </Instrument>
    <Instrument TICKER="APPL" />
    <SF></SF>
</Response>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Response>
   <All>
      <Instrument>
         <Date value="2010-09-02">
            <Quantity>10</Quantity>
            <SAF xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">1</SAF>
            <SAR xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">2</SAR>
         </Date>
         <DXLID>1</DXLID>
      </Instrument>
      <Instrument>
         <Date value="2010-09-02">
            <Quantity>20</Quantity>
         </Date>
         <DXLID>2</DXLID>
      </Instrument>
      <Instrument xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
         <Date value="2010-09-02">
            <SAF>1</SAF>
            <SAR>2</SAR>
         </Date>
         <DXLID>3</DXLID>
      </Instrument>
   </All>
</Response>
```

**Do note:**

1. **The namespace nodes will not appear if the second document is in its own file** -- it is included in the current transformation just for convenience.
2. **All nodes of the first document are procesed first** (if some of them have matching nodes in the second document, the merge is performed).
3. **Finally, all `<Instrument>` nodes from the second document that do not have corresponding `<Instrument>` nodes from the 1st documents, are copied** into the output.
4. **Matching `Date` nodes from the two documents are identified using keys**.